# Convert SKNode to a vectorized image where the SKNode varies in size and suport different screen sizes

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, sprite-kit, sknode

I am using a modified version of the example shown [here](https://github.com/denniswave/RoomPlan-2D/blob/main/RoomPlan%202D/Floor%20Plan/FloorPlanScene.swift) to convert a RoomPlan scan to a SpriteKit SKScene showing a floor plan of the scanned room shown below.

I want to convert this view into into an image that a user can download and view on their computer or other applications, zooming into different sections how they want. The room scan may vary greatly depending on the size of a room they scan, and the device they use may also vary in size greatly (iPad vs iPhone).

My first attempt is to get the camera to zoom out and reposition based on the device size but I could not figure out how to do this. After this was done I figure a screenshot may suffice. This seems like it may not work well for large scans since I don't think a screenshot would contain the vector data?

Second would be some way to convert the SKNode use directly into a vectorized image but my research comes up short on how this may be done.

Any suggestions?

[image: floor plan in app].

Comment: short answer is that, no, i don't think there's any way to output from spritekit to a vector-based image format. you'd have to write that yourself. svg would be the easiest i'd bet.